# How to encrypt a file in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, socket.io

I am trying to somehow encrypt a txt, mp3 or any other file in node.js. I am using socket.io. I am building application to send a file to another client and I would like to encrypt the file before I send it. Here is the onsubmit function where I would like to encrypt the file.

```
form.onsubmit = function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();

            var file = document.getElementById('file');     
            var uploadIds = uploader.upload(file, {
                data: { }
            });
        };
```

This is the whole script on the client side and the form:

```
<form id="form" align="center">
    <input type="file" id="file" value=multiple/> <!--multiple - za več fajlov-->
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<script>
        var person = prompt("Please enter your name:"); //uporabnik vnese ime

        var socket = io();
        socket.emit('join', person);
        var uploader = new SocketIOFileClient(socket);
        var form = document.getElementById('form');

        form.onsubmit = function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();

            var file = document.getElementById('file');     
            var uploadIds = uploader.upload(file, {
                data: { }
            });
        };

    </script>
```

and here is the function where I receive the file on server side:

```
function make(){
    var uploader = new SocketIOFile(socket, {
            uploadDir: 'PREJETO ' + socket.person,   // kam naloži file
            accepts: ['audio/mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'text/plain', 'application/json'],  //  tipi datotek
            maxFileSize: 4194304,   // najvecja dovoljena velikost
            chunkSize: 10240,                           
            transmissionDelay: 0,   // delay
            overwrite: true         // prepišemo če datoteka ze obstaja
    });

    uploader.on('start', (fileInfo) => {
        console.log('#U| Start uploading');

    });
    uploader.on('stream', (fileInfo) => {
        console.log(`${fileInfo.wrote} / ${fileInfo.size} byte(s)`);
    });
    uploader.on('complete', (fileInfo) => {
        console.log('#U| Upload Complete.');
        console.log(fileInfo);
    });
    uploader.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('#U| Error!', err);
    });
    uploader.on('abort', (fileInfo) => {
        console.log('#U| Aborted: ', fileInfo);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the Crypto library: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html. It might be what you need

Comment: I can't find the part where is says something about encrypting any file...just some strings etc.

Comment: Why not encrypt the file on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FileReader to read the contents of the file, and Encrypt it using Crypto, as suggested by Steve. Then use your current code to send the encrypted file.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/filereader
https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Comment: So I have read the content of a file with FileReader and I have encrypted data. So how do I convert encrypted data back to file so I can send it?

Comment: Great! I recommend writing the encrypted data into a file using a package like Write, and then send the file as you normally would. https://www.npmjs.com/package/write

Comment: One more question: When I encrypt .txt file I can normaly decrypt it, but when I try to encrypt .mp3 or .docx, it says that the file is broken when I try to open it after decryption ... Any suggestions?

Comment: I would compare the original file with the new one to get some clues (using an editor that allows you to see the bytes). If you're writing strings to the file, you could be running into encoding issues.